# JavaScript array comparison(They don't need to be ===)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Long story short, I'm learning js. I gave myself a project and I'm stuck.
My Project:
It's a gambling game where you pick 6 numbers, and they draw 35-48 numbers, faster you get your 6 numbers the larger your winnings, simple.

I'm stuck at arrays, I should have 3 arrays:

1. 1-48 range
2. 35 number from 48 thats random generated
3. the 6 numbers that the user inputed.

I'm stuck at the 3 array, I don't know what function to use to check i my 2.array has the 6 elements from the 3.array.

Here is My code(I did not write the 3.Array becous I don't know where to start):

```
var x = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48'];

var y = x.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length), 1)[0];


function as() {
    var y = x.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length), 1)[0];
    document.write(y + '</br>');


}

function Radnom13Brojeva() {
    for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        as();
    };
}
```

Comment: Depending on whether this is a [Node JS app](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/) or [a browser app](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp), you'll need slightly different approaches for retrieving user input. In the browser, there's almost infinitely many ways to build an interface for user input, but `window.prompt` might work well for you as you're starting out.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if an array contains a certain element, javascript has 2 methods to do so, [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

//indexOf()
console.log(arr.indexOf(4));   //output: 3
console.log(arr.indexOf("None existing element"));  //output: -1

//includes()
console.log(arr.includes(4));  //output: true
console.log(arr.includes("None existing element"));  //output: false
```

Keep in mind however that includes() was introduced with EM6 and does not have as extensive a browser support as indexOf(). The most prominent exclusion being IE.